# check for null with HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: asp.net

How do you check for null with HtmlAgilityPack? I'm getting "Property or indexer 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.HasChildNodes' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" with the following.

```
if (Node.Element("TD").HasChildNodes = DBNull.Value)
```

I"m getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. " with

```
if (Node.Element("TD").HasChildNodes)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the `=` operator is the assignment operator, not the comparison operator (`==`). In your first example you are trying to assign `DBNull.Value` to `HasChildeNodes`, a read-only property, not compare it to a value.

Second, you don't test against `DBNull.Value`, but against `null`. `DBNull.Value` is to be used when testing values of items returned by the database using ADO.NET. For all other cases, you should use `null`.

So, the test should be:

```
if (Node.Element("TD").HasChildNodes == null)
```

Comment: maybe it's `=` because it's vb.net ?

Comment: @Bala - with an `if ()` and no `Then`?

Comment: Hi I tried if (Node.Element("TD").HasChildNodes == null) and I'm getting "The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'bool' is never equal to 'null' of type 'bool'

Comment: @l9429727 try `if (Node!=null && Node.Element("TD")!=null && Node.Elements("TD").HasChildren )`

Comment: Hi thank you for responding! I didn't notice until I opened the thread. When I set a break point on 'if (Node != null && Node.Element("TD") != null)' the value of 'Node.Element("TD")' in the immediate window is null but the innerhtml of 'Node' has '<td>' tags. ??? 'Tr1TdNode.Elements("TD")' doesn't have 'HasChildren' so I didn't include it. I have an else statement but it's not giving me preoblems.